# HTTPWebRequest Response Error when sending SOAP

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

I am using XDocument to manually build a SOAP request and send it using HTTPWebRequest. The final output of the XDocument object is valid and when I capture and send it to the end point using SOAPUI it works fine, however; I have been unable to get this to work using HTTPWebRequest. I receive internal server server errors, but nothing really specific that I can work from. I am excluding the XDocument object for brevity. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
        var _url = "http://xxx.xx.x.xx:9191/aa/bb/cc/dd";
        var _action = "http://xxx.xx.x.xx:9191/aa/bb/cc/dd?op=submit";


        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(_url);
        webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAPAction", _action);
        webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxx", "xxxxxx");
        webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";



        using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            xd.Save(stream);
        }


        // get the response from the completed web request.
        string soapResult;
        try
        {
            using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                }
                Response.Write(soapResult);
            }

        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                Response.Write("Status Code : " + ((HttpWebResponse) ex.Response).StatusCode);
                Response.Write("Status Description : " + ((HttpWebResponse) ex.Response).StatusDescription);
            }

        }
```

UPDATE (included small sample of SOAP):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <enrollment xmlns="xxxxxxxxxxx">
         <asOfDate xmlns="">2018-01-01</asOfDate>
         <activate xmlns="">false</activate>
         <subscription xmlns="">
            <receiptDate>2018-06-01</receiptDate>
            <accountMatchData>
               <accountHccIdentifier>
                  <accountHccIdentificationNumber>xxxxxxxxxx</accountHccIdentificationNumber>
               </accountHccIdentifier>
               <asOfDate>2018-01-01</asOfDate>
            </accountMatchData>
            <informationSourceCode>
               <codeEntry>3</codeEntry>
            </informationSourceCode>
         </subscription>
      </enrollment>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

UPDATE (Solved):
I cannot believe it was something as stupid as how it was sending the credentials. I used the below code to generate the credentials and add them to the HTTPWebRequest and it worked.

```
  string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("xxxx" + ":" + "xxxxxxx"));

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(_url);            
            webRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format(
                "Basic {0}", credentials);
```

Comment: I am not using a WSDL reference for this. I built the request manually using XDocument, copy and pasted the SOAP into SOAP UI, Validated against the WSDL successfully and sent it successfully. The errors being returned are Status Code : InternalServerError , Status Description : Server Error

Comment: It seems the error is happening on the line with webRequest.GetResponse()

Comment: I added the SOAP to the code above. The only thing missing is the code where I build the SOAP using XDocument and XElement.

Comment: Good point. Write is not an available option though the way it is currently written. xd is the SOAP object.

Comment: Save should be valid. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Solved. Thank you for the help. It was an issue with the method I was sending the credentials. The error was Internal Server Error 500 so it was not very specific. I just kept rewriting different sections of my code until I stumbled across the solution.